# How to position links on the right side of text?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner, and I am trying to get this to work.
How do I position the link to the right side of the connect text?
I want the text links to be inline but to the right.

```css
.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  margin-top: 38px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  height: 700px;
}

.footer-text {
  padding: 200px 100px;
  font-family: "Khula", sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #222222;
}

.footer-contact {
  font-family: "Khula", sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #222222;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 100px 60px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-text">Contact</div>

<ul>
  <li><a href=email.html class="footer-contact">Email</a></li>
  <li><a href=linkedin.html class="footer-contact">LinkedIn</a></li>
  <li><a href=instagram.html class="footer-contact">Instagram</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: *"the connect text"* what is a *connect* text?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: I believe it's a typo for "Contact".

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the .footer-text:

```
display:flex;
justify-content: right;
```

Note that this will apply to all childs of the .footer-text div.

Answer (score 0):

Please update this two class properties as like the following code:

```css
.footer-text {
    padding: 200px 100px;
    font-family: "Khula", sans-serif;

    font-size: 80px;
    color: #222222;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be solved easily by using a wrapper div. like so,

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer-text {
  float: left;
}

.ul {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="footer-text">Contact</div>

  <ul class="ul">

    <li><a href=email.html class="footer-contact">Email</a></li>
    <li><a href=linkedin.html class="footer-contact">LinkedIn</a></li>
    <li><a href=instagram.html class="footer-contact">Instagram</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```